# SQLite insertion issue

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have SQLite database for my application. I am able to retrieve values from my SQLite table  and inserting values with no SQL error but unable to find in SQLite table. I just got stuck at this point. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableString *registrationquery=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_kicks values ('%@','%@','%@')",[totalkicks text],[sessionstart text],[sessionstart text],@"0"];      

//NSString *sqlNSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO 'tbl_kicks' VALUES('%d','%@','%@');",  

// 4,sessionstart.text, appDelegate.note];

const char *sqlString = [registrationquery UTF8String];
char *sqlError;
sqlite3_exec( appDelegate.database, sqlString, NULL, NULL, &sqlError );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have a prepare statement. You should try to use sqlite3_prepare_v2 and read the error code which it returns if any, after that only execute.